# Does a submarine cruise underwater or sail underwater?

Tags: phrases

The submarine had been cruising in the Atlantic for three weeks

Comment: “*The question of whether computers can think is like the question of whether submarines can swim.*” ― Edsger W. Dijkstra.

Comment: Er, but can a plane fly? And if so, does the plane fly like a fly or like a bird? And so, which learned to fly first, the bird or the fly? (Obviously the expected answer should be the fly, else planes would be birding, not flying.) -- :)

Answer (score 4):

Google ngram result for 'submarine cruise' can be found [here](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=submarine+cruise&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csubmarine%20cruise%3B%2Cc0). And for 'submarine sail' [here](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=submarine%20sail&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1;,submarine%20sail;,c0).

'sail' is used as a verb in relation to submarine in [this](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=tlnbpCOwrWYC&lpg=PA40&dq=%22submarine%20sail%22&pg=PA31#v=onepage&q=sail&f=false) specialist publication about a submarine called the Dreadnought.

'cruise' seems more often to be used as an adjective or a noun, rather than a verb.

The [etymology of 'cruise'](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=cruise&searchmode=none) links to 'crossing' and 'chasing', so '[sail](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=sail&searchmode=none)' seems the most apposite choice for normal, non-allegorical usage. That said, it could be a deliberate use of 'cruising' to imply hostile intent.

Comment: Underwater vessels of transport are relatively recent and words already in existence have had their senses extended to fit. We are quite happy to talk about sailing to the Isle of Man, say, even though there's never a sail in sight. 'Steaming' has been used on occasion for travelling on steamships, but not, to my knowledge, 'dieselling' or 'nuclearing'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth you are correct, it even extends to sci-fi. I would like to add that [Oxford Dictionary](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/sail?q=sail) suggests the use of adverbial or object when the vessel has no real sails.

Comment: @Mindwin More precisely it implies that the non-use of an adverbial or object (We went sailing) only occurs with sailboats. The other usages usually (Has the 'Discovery' / 'QE II' sailed?)  or always have an adverbial or object, whether referencing a sailboat or powered vessel.

Comment: But if you run [*cruise* and *sail*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=submarine+sail%2C+submarine+cruise&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csubmarine%20sail%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csubmarine%20cruise%3B%2Cc0) together, *cruise* comes up twice as often.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, 'sail' as a verb is used to describe the object being afloat of the liquid in question. As it is clearly understood, that a submarine is underwater, the notion that it 'sails' sounds absurd to me. So I would say, that a submarine cruises underwater.

Comment: Subs are not always submerged.

Comment: @Kshitij when you go to sci-fi literature, spaceships are often described as sailing in vacuum. The verb sail has detached from the proper object "sail" in this regard.