# Do submarines float?

Tags: meaning, verbs, word-usage

Is it correct to say that a submarine floats if it is below the water surface?

According to the dictionary definition, it seems to me that this is a correct way to refer to a submerged submarine.

[Merriam Webster - float](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/float): to rest on the surface of or be suspended in a fluid.
[Oxford - float](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/float): Be suspended freely in a liquid or gas.
[Oxford - float](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/float): Move or hover slowly and lightly in a liquid or the air.

The way I understand it, **in a liquid or fluid** means within the medium, not on the surface.
Is this the proper meaning?

Comment: if it's not at the bottom of the ocean, any position above the ocean floor is "suspended" therefore yes, it floats.

Comment: @SrJoven, your notion is wrong.  Eg: When Titanic sank, it took 10 to 15 minutes to go from the surface to the bottom.  In that period it was not at the bottom of the ocean, but it wasn't floating, it was sinking.

Comment: related [Does a submarine cruise underwater or sail underwater?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/160179/does-a-submarine-cruise-underwater-or-sail-underwater)

Comment: I'm confused. What's wrong with the definition you pulled out: "Be suspended freely in a liquid or gas." Suspended in liquid (ie. neither rising or sinking) is precisely what you're talking about.

Comment: @jwpat7 Your response is misleading.  The term "float" implicitly assumes a steady-state condition.  Once the Titanic was done sinking, it was proud (in contact w/ the floor), and clearly not floating.

Comment: jwpat, you're wrong.  Joven said "any position suspended". note the suspended.  in your titanic example, it was not suspended.

Comment: @JoeBlow, SrJoven wrote “any position above the ocean floor is "suspended" therefore yes, it floats”.  While Titanic was sinking, it was of course in a position above the ocean floor.  It may have been [suspended](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/suspended#Adjective) (in the sense *delayed*) as it sank, but rather than floating, it was sinking.

Comment: @jwpat7 I regret that I didn't include "stationary" or "stable" in the statement of suspended. Any *stable* position that is above the floor is *suspended* and therefore, neutrally buoyant, therefore floating. And even if it's on the surface of the sea, it's still *neutrally* buoyant because it can't be pushed above the surface of the sea. (Unless it can, then it's positively buoyant).

Comment: jwpat - fair enough.  SrJ has now clarified!  Just FTR in certain contexts I'd say you certainly can refer to it as floating (after all, it's not in a free-fall: a vacuum) even if it is moving down.

Comment: Technically, it depends on the design of the sub, and it's current "trim".  A sub may have "neutral buoyancy", or it may be heavier or lighter than the water it displaces.  I believe that most military subs are normally trimmed (by letting water into the ballast tanks) to have a slight "negative buoyancy", then they keep from sinking by "flying" through the water with their fins, propelled by the prop.

Comment: One might note that "float" may be used in the sense of "The leaf floated through the air," even though the leaf was clearly sinking if you watched it for a period of time.  The term has several different meanings.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Objects *under* water can *float, rise or sink.*

This is a Galileo-type thermometer:

[image: fluid-filled cylinders with glass fluid- and air-filled bubbles floating at different levels]

Depending on the temperature of the fluid in which the sealed glass fluid containing sealed bubbles are suberged, they will either rise, sink, or float at certain levels. Per [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galileo_thermometer):

> The only factor that determines whether a large object rises or falls in a particular liquid is the object's density relative to the density of the liquid. If the object is denser than the liquid then it sinks, as it is heavier than the liquid it displaces. If the object is less dense than the liquid then it begins to sink until the weight of the displaced liquid becomes equal to the object's weight; *then it floats at that depth.*

So, yes, a submarine floats at a certain depth in the ocean. If it is to surface, it rises, or it sinks to a lower depth. It works on *Archimedes' principle*:

> Archimedes' principle is the law of buoyancy. It states that "any body partially or completely submerged in a fluid is buoyed up by a force equal to the weight of the fluid displaced by the body." The weight of an object acts downward, and the buoyant force provided by the displaced fluid acts upward. ***If these two forces are equal, the object floats.*** Density is defined as weight per volume. If the density of an object exceeds the density of water, the object will sink. - Office of Naval Research

Comment: The problem here is float has two meanings. It can be "floating on the surface" or "floating submerged in the water". To eliminate this confusion "hovering" is used also for "floating submerged in the water".

Comment: @ermanen: Lighter-than-air craft are said to float, even though they generally don't get anywhere close to the top of the atmosphere.

Answer (score 28):

I don't want to detract from medica's accurate answer, except to add another point of view about the word *float* and then discuss the jargon of submarine operations.

First, there is room for [poetic license](http://www.ussalbacore.org/html/early_life/early_life_praenuntius_futuri_1/early_life_praenuntius_futuri_1.html) with the word *float*, to the point where these uses are as natural and accurate as the precise meaning you might be looking for.

Parachutes, paper airplanes, and wind dispersed seeds all float gently to the ground, the buoyant force and fluid dynamics not quite or not always balancing the weight.

A seagull floats, wings outstretched and motionless, on the air rising over a dune. (The bird is actually sinking through the air, but, since the air is rising, it appears to be floating.)

Astronauts float in space, where there is no fluid to float in.

In the world of modern naval submarines, they have [their own jargon](http://www.navy.mil/navydata/cno/n87/usw/issue_5/dive_eye_view.html) to be precise about what they do:

- Resting motionless at a fixed depth is *hovering* (used when launching a missile).
- Traveling at a fixed depth, ascending and descending while traveling is *[flying](http://www.ussalbacore.org/html/early_life/early_life_praenuntius_futuri_1/early_life_praenuntius_futuri_1.html)*.
- Going deeper in a controlled manner is *diving*.
- Going deeper without control is *sinking*.

Comment: There's also *submerging* and *surfacing*

Comment: I would say that astronauts *drift* rather than float, although I guess that also refers to a fluid medium.

Comment: _Floating_ is used in the jargon also, if submarine is resting on the surface. In this case, it has a positive buoyancy.

Comment: @TylerH *drift* suggests motion

Comment: @SrJoven: If it is resting submerged in the water, then it has a neutral buoyancy. If it is resting on the surface (floating on the surface), it has a positive buoyancy. You can do a research about this.

Comment: @ermanen I guess I can't argue with [wikipedia](https://www.google.com/search?q=define+positive+buoyancy) "An object that floats in the water is known as being positively buoyant."  I think it's positively buoyant with respect to *water*, but neutral with respect to buoyancy in general (that is, the fact if it goes up or down.) But alas, I am wrong on the Internet. :)

Comment: @njzk2 have you ever seen a ship *float* completely still? They're never devoid of motion.

Comment: @TylerH: the notion of *floating* indicates that the ship stays above water (or at a given depth, for a sub), while *drifting* relates to how it moves off its course.

Comment: What do you call it when it's rising towards the surface, whether or not it will actually surface in the immediate future?

Answer (score 5):

The OED has fifteen separate main meanings of the verb ***float***, each with many sub-meanings. Only one of them, 3a, deals with an object floating on the surface of a liquid. Another (I think under '5') deals with the submarine situation. Yet others deal with such things as a parachute 'floating to the ground' i.e. floating whilst sinking.

If you are seriously interested in this the OED is worth a visit.

Answer (score 3):

A submarine operates by changing its *buoyancy*. If the average density of the submarine is less than that of the surrounding water it floats on the surface. To dive the submarine increases its density by taking water into buoyancy tanks. When its overall density increases above that of the water it sinks.

Once the necessary depth has been reached the vessel will adjust for neutral buoyancy, where its density is the same as the surrounding water, and then the depth can be further controlled by the horizontal equivalent of a rudder.

So submarines *can* float, but they can also sink and "hover" at neutral buoyancy. This latter condition can't really be called floating.

Answer (score 1):

One would not usually describe a submarine as 'floating', particularly if submerged. It could be termed to be "at sea", to be "underway" (or "under way"), or to be "making way". A couple of other suitable terms are available, depending on the situation.

More-or-less-technical terms (British English, recognised by mariners internationally due to their use in the International [CollRegs](http://en.wikisource.org/wiki/International_Regulations_for_Preventing_Collisions_at_Sea), not specific to submarines):

Any sea-faring vessel that is going from one place to another is **making a passage** or 'passage-making'. It might also be **at sea** (not so much a technical term).

A seafaring vessel (of any kind) is **under way** (or **underway**) if it is:

- not aground
- not at anchor
- not made fast to a dock, the shore, or other stationary object.

If it is propelled (by any means including sails or engine but not including tidal drift or wind drift) then it is **making way**.

So a submarine under power would be **under way** - if it's not under power but it's also not moored or anchored or aground then it's **under way, not making way**.

If it is unable to maneuver (e.g. because its means of propulsion have failed) then it is **not under command**. This is typically a bad thing.

If it is sitting submerged on the seabed and can't get up again then it has **sunk**. Best to avoid this.

[International Regulations for Preventing Collisions at Sea](http://en.wikisource.org/wiki/International_Regulations_for_Preventing_Collisions_at_Sea) (on Wikisource)

[Use of the terms 'under way' and 'making way' defined in "Farwell's Rules of the Nautical Road"](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=nlIYDrgc1ncC&lpg=PA67&ots=0eybDtUV3L&dq=%22under%20way%22%20%22making%20way%22&pg=PA67#v=onepage&q=%22under%20way%22%20%22making%20way%22&f=false)

The BBC has used "sit in waters" in a [news story](http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/uk-scotland-highlands-islands-11605365):

> Aside from attack capabilities, it is able to sit in waters off the coast undetected, delivering the UK's special forces where needed

but I think that sounds weird (personal opinion).

Answer (score 1):

Objects in liquids can have positive, negative or neutral buoyancy. At positive buoyancy they will **float** upwards, and negative buoyancy they will **sink** downwards, and at neutral buoyancy they will remain where they are.

A submerged submarine will be in these various states at various times. During the times it is at a steady depth it will have neutral buoyancy, and so can be said to be neither floating nor sinking.

Comment: Can you source *float* for upward buoyancy?

Comment: No, but I can do the reverse: according to Merriam-Webster, "buoyancy" is "the tendency of a body to float or to rise when submerged in a fluid." Underwater the term buoyancy is used in preference to words like "sink" and "float", I suppose because those terms are ambiguous once you're below the surface.

Comment: Float *or* rise? The point of float is that the density underneath is the same as the density above. A ship floats on water because the density underneath it is equivalent to the density above it. In theory, it could be above the water (see dirigible or hot air balloon) but once it's at a fixed height, what's it doing (assuming it's not being self-propelled)?

Comment: You don't have to say "float upwards". It just floats. But it is correct that it floats when it has a positive buoyancy.

Comment: @SrJoven: I didn't say "rise". It rests actually when it floats.

Comment: @SrJoven: An object that floats in the water is known as being positively buoyant. An object that sinks to the bottom is negatively buoyant, while an object that hovers at the same level in the water is neutrally buoyant.

Comment: @SrJoven: If you disagree, you disagree with physics. It is not my opinion. You can say it first rises, then floats. Echelon could say "rise upwards" and then floats. We are on the same page, no need to disagree.

Comment: @ermanen it's neutrally buoyant at the point that it's not sinking and not rising. It can be argued that a submarine floats to the top and it can be argued that a balloon floats to the ground. Now, given that, which direction is float?

Comment: Since this is now a discussion about the meaning of "float": an old Collins English dictionary I have defines it as to "be buoyant or cause to exhibit buoyancy." And every scuba diver understands that positive buoyancy means you will float; and this floating will make you travel upwards with increasing speed as the surrounding pressure decreases, until you reach the surface.

Comment: Well you will leave the surface if you deflate your BCD and you become negatively buoyant again. That's what your weights are for.

Comment: Yes, there is a confusion between meanings of "float". It can be floating on the surface or floating submerged in the water. Floating submerged in the water is called hovering also. But floating never means rising. If buoyancy is greater than weight, the object rises. If it reaches the surface, it floats. Floating on the surface has a positive buoyancy but floating submerged in the water has a neutral buoyancy. Is it clear now? :)

Comment: OK, you won't continue to go above the surface of the water. Your positive buoyancy stops at the point where it's no longer effective at pushing you up.

Comment: @ermanen I agree that an object "floating submerged in the water has a neutral buoyancy." That was my original point... seems a long time ago now :)

Comment: @Echelon: I up-voted your answer already but you can clarify further also based on our discussion.

Answer (score 1):

Submariners do not refer to submarines as floating. While a submarine may often be trimmed to be neutrally buoyant, it can also hold depth while under power and negatively or positively buoyant due to the dynamic pressure of water flowing over its control surfaces.

Answer (score 0):

*Float* has two distinct, but related meanings. In fact, it is possible to see the two meanings as being (1) quite the same thing,  or (2) contradictory, depending on context.

1. To stay on the surface, as an air-filled ball or a piece of cork, even a drop (film) of oil, on a body of liquid.
2. To keep off the bottom of a body of liquid (the surface at the bottom). Wrecked ships are "floated" (raised off the bottom of the sea) upwards in a slow and tedious process.

Yes, submarines *do* float, else they cannot move.

But no, submarines **do not** float, they would get spotted and destroyed by enemy fire.

Comment: a submarine that's stationary just over the bottom and has all noisy machinery turned down can be next to impossible to detect, especially by someone who doesn't have a highly accurate sonar map of the ocean floor in that area. Similar with one floating just under an inversion layer, just keeping station.

Answer (score -2):

Submarines are driven by an engine and can change course. So I would not say they float, they move.

Comment: they can however be stationary both on the surface and submerged, using at most pumps and propulsion systems for station keeping.

Comment: Is that the normal movement of submarines unter water?

Comment: depends entirely on the mission, obviously. If you're trying to stay undetected while observing something, you want to move as little as possible and make no noise. If you're going somewhere in  hurry you're going to be going fast :)