# Is there a word for a fish's stationary position

Tags: single-word-requests

When a fish is being still in one spot, it definitely isn't floating or hovering.  Poised?  Suspended?  "She made out a school of tiny fish ____ in a patch of filtered sunlight".

Comment: I like "suspended".  Maybe "drifting" could work?

Comment: Not an answer, but unless the fish being perfectly still is important, you could always omit the verb. *She made out a school of tiny fish in a patch of filtered sunlight.* sounds fine to me.

Comment: I think I've occasionally heard "suspended".

Comment: I like suspended, or, related, ***hovering***.

Comment: Are they actively swimming to stay in the sun patch, or is the water still as well?

Comment: Related question: [Do Submarines Float?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/204723/do-submarines-float)

Answer (score 1):

*Any of the following words would do:*

Unmoving (quite poetic)

Stock-still

Immobile

Static

Unwavering

Motionless

Answer (score 1):

Why not **hovering?**

> 1. to float in the air without moving in any direction
> 2. to stay very close to a person or place
> 3. to stay near a specified point or level
>
> [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hover)

It seems to capture both stillness but also the fine flutters and oscillations you see when you spot a group of minnows just hanging out. Plus, it brings to mind motion through air, which, when talking about fish, is an imaginative touch.

or **Wavering**, maybe with a modifier? (barely wavering? hardly wavering?)

> to sway to and fro, to tremble

Other suggestions:

**blinking**, **quivering**, **winking**, **glimmering**

Answer (score 0):

I think ***[floating](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/floating) immobile*** may describe the scene:

> - Buoyed on or suspended in or as if in a fluid. (AHD)

- Periodically, fish rose next to the bank, but they were not taking anything ... that move on the water *instead of floating immobile* before springing into flight. From: [A Guide’s Guide to Fly-Fishing Mistakes: “Presenting the Fly”](http://midcurrent.com/techniques/a-guides-guide-to-fly-fishing-mistakes-presenting-the-fly/)

Answer (score 0):

[Standstill](http://www.tripadvisor.com/LocationPhotoDirectLink-g187497-d195124-i78138753-L_Aquarium_de_Barcelona-Barcelona_Catalonia.html) is used in this context.

And very, *very* rarely, even [swimstill](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=GEcTAQAAIAAJ&q=%22swimstill%22&dq=%22swimstill%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=8EaRVZTPJcadugS9xYD4Dw&ved=0CC4Q6AEwAw). I think it's a neologism, but it's a good one.

Comment: Is standstill also an adjective?

Comment: @Josh61: Not according to dictionaries. But we do have compounds like [standstill agreement](http://www.investopedia.com/terms/s/standstill_agreement.asp)

Comment: Yes, I was just wondering if the sentence "they were just standstill" is grammatical. Interesting finding, though!

Comment: In this context, "swimstill" would be too clever and cute for its own good, imho.

Answer (score 0):

I can't come up with a word that is specific to aquatic life, but here's a couple suggestions:

frozen, lingering

"Frozen" is more neutral as far as imputing meaning to the fishes' activity, and it's also alliterative ;)

Answer (score 0):

You could say that the fish are ***resting*** when they are not swimming.

For a bit of whimsical irony, you could say:

> She made out a school of tiny fish ***bathing*** in a patch of filtered sunlight.

Comment: But if there's a current, the fish needs to do work to stay stationary.

Comment: @PeterShor: I would call that *treading water*.

Comment: How can a fish *tread* water when it has no feet. :-)

Comment: @PeterShor: Fine, *idiomatically* treading water. :-)

Answer (score 0):

**[Suspended](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/suspend)**

> 11) to come to a stop, usually temporarily; cease from operation for a time.
>    14) to be suspended, as in a liquid, gas, etc.

from Dictionary.com